# Prove that if $Q(x) \mid P(x)$ and $P(x) \mid Q(x)$ then $Q(x)=cP(x)$ where $c≠0$ is a constant

Tags: polynomials

I am having hard time proving this theorem in polynomial algebra. I would appreciate any tips or advice on approaching this task.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Think about the degrees of the polynomials.

Comment: If $P(x)=a(x)Q(x)$ and $Q(x)=b(x)P(x)$ then $P(x)=a(x)b(x)P(x)$.

Comment: @mairisb What is your try?, Is stack exchange a Question-Answer machine?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown do you mean the fact that they must be polynomials of the same degree?

Comment: @lulu That's what I wrote when I first approached the task but I don't see how does that prove the fact that apparently Q(x)=cP(x)?

Comment: We have $a(x)b(x)=1$.  Deduce that both $a(x),b(x)$ must be constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

1) If $Q$ divides $P$, then by definition there exists a polynomial $R$ such that $P=R\cdot Q$.

2) $deg(R\cdot Q)=deg(R)+deg(Q)$, where $deg$ is the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: So I understand that it means that P=QR1 and Q=PR2 where R1 and R2 are some other polynomials, but what does the degree of these polynomials have to do with this?

Comment: As an example, let $P(x)=x^2$. The answerers have deduced then that $x^2=a(x)b(x)\cdot x^2$, this means that $a(x)b(x)=1$. They've then used the rule given in Mundron's second hint to show you they are both constant as a result.

Comment: Many thanks, I totally got it now. I never thought in term of degrees of these polynomials on my own. It means that the deg(R1(x)R2(x)) = 0 and that means that it is a number.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
P(x) = u(x)Q(x)\\
Q(x) = v(x)P(x)
$$

then

$$
P(x) = u(x)v(x)P(x)\Rightarrow \mbox{deg}(u(x)v(x))=0\Rightarrow\mbox{deg}(u(x)) = \mbox{deg}(v(x))= 0
$$

Answer (score 0):

By definition of polynomial division only a polynomial of lower or equal degree can divide a polynomial of higher or equal degree.
Here however both polynomials divide each other hence their degree must be the same. 
As for the coefficients ... if the corresponding coefficients are not the same or multiple of each other (for these two same degree polynomials) then any of the two divisions will give a remainder that would be function of x leading to reduction or gain of degree for one of the polynomials in the division process thus contradicting the correct 'same degree' hypothesis...hope this helps.